# autoplot using wrong time for xts

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts, arima, forecast

I used `autoplot()` function to plot a time series data including the arima forecast from the `forecast()` function. The x-axis of the plot is wrong. The data is used xts from 2000/01/01 to 2019/09/01, but obviously the result is not using this time.

```
fed.arima <- auto.arima(FEDFUNDS_ts)
fore1 <- forecast(fed.arima,level = c(95),h=12)
plot(fore1)
autoplot(fore1)
```

[plot(fore1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XnRS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNHF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your time data is character type. So change time or date type data.

Example :

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   ~ obs. of  ~ variables:
 $ Time: chr  "2017/7/1" "2017/7/2" "2017/7/3" "2017/7/4 " ...

library(lubridate)
data$Time<-ymd(data$Time)
str(data)
'data.frame':   ~ obs. of  ~ variables:
 $ Time: Date, format  "2017-7-1" "2017-7-2" "2017-7-3" "2017-7-4 " ...
```

And try to do make plot.